# How to update variable in the forloop flow?

Tags: c

This is a piece of my `C` code:

```
for (i=2; i<sequence_length+1; i++)
{
    int tab_length = Newton(sequence_length, i);
    start_tab[tab_length] = make_for_num(i, sequence_length, start_tab, tab_length);

}
```

My goal is to use updated `start_tab` variable for every next step of forloop. Output of each iteration should be an input for the next one, but it isn't. How can I fix that?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Variable start_tab  is updated in each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function.

Comment: Can you explain your comment for the benefit of the OP. He may not understand the setup, the test or where to place the recursive call.

Comment: He can google/bing for what a recursive function is and there are tons of examples online. I have confidence he will easily be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for effort. It just so happen that I know what a recursive funcion is and I have used this concept now with a success :)